# Apache Rewrite Works for IE 7 but also effects newer IE versions

Tags: regex, apache, internet-explorer

I have a site that I would like to redirect users using a version of IE less than 8.
I have created several variations of regex for IE 7, but every time, the redirect also effects IE 11.

I don't want IE > 7 users to be effected.

Here are my Apache rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.7.*
RewriteRule ^index.php subindex.php 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.6.*
RewriteRule ^index.php subindex.php 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.5.*
RewriteRule ^index.php subindex.php
```

I have also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [5-7]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php subindex.php
```

To add to problem, the site is an intranet site, and the target users browsers are in Compatibility mode for intranet sites.
I need to be able to override the compatibility mode, so I added this to my .htaccess:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
```

and also tried this:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=8,chrome=1"
```

Just for kicks, I also replaced the edge with 8 and 9 and 10 just to see if it made a difference.
No change. IE 7 breaks my site, so I need to redirect those users, but newer IE users in compatibility mode need to see the non-redirect site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[User agent sniffing is evil](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/), and wastes server resources here that are better put to use elsewhere. Let the browser choose for itself:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.tld/subindex.php">
<![endif]-->
```

The [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) mask this line of code from any non-IE browser and IE10+, and are ignored because of the 'lesser than' rule by IE8/9. The meta-rule just performs a direct redirect (0 seconds delay) to the target URL.

[Some bonus reading on why user agent sniffing is just... no.](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Comment: Thanks, I had looked tried this approach before, but the compatibility mode was causing IE 11 to emulate to a lower version.

Your approach combined with the returning the header worked.    `Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"`